# wcf progressive download

Tags: android, wcf, progressive-download

I am trying to write a WCF service that can send mp3 files to the client. I need it to transfer the mp3 file using progressive download because the client is an android app and I want it to start playing as soon as possible. How can I do progressive download using WCF? Is it possible?

Here's what I have so far. This seems to work but its not progressive download. It plays in the android app but only after the whole file has been downloaded.

Service contract:

```
[OperationContract, WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetFileStream/?filepath={virtualPath}")]
    Stream GetFileStream(string virtualPath);
```

Service Configuration:

```
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="streamedHttpBinding" transferMode="StreamedResponse"
                     maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000">
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <service name="...">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restful" binding="webHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="streamedHttpBinding"
                contract="..." />

     </service>
     <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="restful">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

If you can provide links to sources about progressive download, that would be helpful as well. My googling has not turned up much for progressive download + wcf. Appreciate your help.

Android code:

```
player.reset();
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
player.setDataSource(path);
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

player is a [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) object. I'm setting the data source to a url in path.

Comment: @nithin: How is your Android app trying to access the mp3 file? What code are you using?

Comment: @MisterSquonk I think the android client is behaving properly. See the code in the updated question.

Comment: @nithin: OK, is there a particular reason why your 'service' end is written with WCF? The effect you want can be achieved with a simple HTTP service.

Comment: @MisterSquonk is right on this one. I assumed something like MonoAndroid was the phone-side client so I'm deleting my answer. It's not applicable.

Comment: @MisterSquonk server-side includes other C# code and so the only two options I know are WCF and ASP.NET web services. I don't know how to do progressive download in either. Is it possible with asp.net services? I haven't looked into it yet.

Comment: @nithin: See my answer for a background to doing this simply with HTTP. The second link for the HTTPListener can be written into a Windows console app, WinForm app or a Windows Service quite easily and just uses C# rather than ASP.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so I figured out what was wrong. WCF does do progressive download. I thought the behavior configuration section was necessary when you are returning Streams from your service. But for a webhttpbinding, in order to do progressive download, it should not be set. Setting the binding configuration to streamedResponse will enable **chunking** and that is not progressive download. Correct configuration is below.

```
<bindings>
</bindings>
<service name="...">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restful" binding="webHttpBinding"
            contract="..." />

 </service>
 <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restful">
            <webHttp />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Note that there is no bindingConfiguration on the endpoint.

Thanks to @MisterSquonk for your comments. they helped me look in the right places.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to this question here [Developing A Streaming Server For Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559468/developing-a-streaming-server-for-android/5560239#5560239) which basically describes simply using IIS as the server to 'open' (and progressively stream) mp3 files using AsyncPlayer on Android (the same works for MediaPlayer).

Also see my answer to the question here [How to communicate over local network between C# desktop application and mobile (android) device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687650/how-to-communicate-over-local-network-between-c-desktop-application-and-mobile/5688006#5688006) which describes a simple HTTPListener 'service' written in C#. It can be used for a variety of things and could be adapted to open an mp3 file which MediaPlayer could stream progressively.

Just some alternative ideas to WCF.